# Prevent Parcel Auto Clear Console

Tags: javascript, parcel

I use Parcel with config below for my project.

```
{
"name": "forkify",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"default": "index.html",
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
},
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0"
}
```

}

When i type `npm start` and change code in js file then save it, my web auto reload but the Parcel clear my console.log(), how to prevent this behavior guys? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="module"` attribute to your script tag in your `index.html` file.

Comment: This is not working for me. What is working is to enable persistent log in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Run the npm run build command and then re-run npm run start command again.

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html` where is your script delete defer and add `type="module"`. Like this: `<script type="module"src="src/js/controller.js"></script>`